# Ksh script using sendmail mail fail when body contains ":"

Tags: escaping, sendmail, ksh

I'm facing a strange behaviour in sendmail 8.14.4 on Solaris.

I succeed sending a mail using ksh script as follow :

```
( echo "Subject: Test"
echo "Date: 20131004"
) | sendmail -f me@somewhere.com -t coworker@somewhere.com
```

But there is no content.

if I use :

```
( echo "Subject: Test"
echo "Date 20131004"
) | sendmail -f me@somewhere.com -t coworker@somewhere.com
```

There is content....

Why is this **:** blocking the content ?

Thanks for answering :-) !

EDIT 1: OK,I've found a workaround setting content type to "plain/html" and add both html nodes.. and it work. but it is a workaround...

Comment: It's strange, the "Hello all" diseappear each time I wrote it ....

Comment: I suspect your question would make more sense if at least you could explain where we are supposed to be seeing this...?

Comment: You should see "Hello All" in the beginning of the message, as it is directed toward you all :-)

Comment: Oh, that. Yes, the question style guidelines are partially enforced by technical means.

Answer (score 2):

The malformed `Date` header violates the email format; traditional Sendmail would typically assume the text is message content, and put it in the body.

Your question appears to be based on a false assumption, namely that headers and body are adjacent. Properly, you need an empty line between headers and body. In the first case, the `Date:` line, though invalid, is likely accepted into the headers.

```
( echo Subject: Test
  echo
  echo Date: 20131004 ) |
sendmail -oi recipient@example.com
```

or even better

```
sendmail -oi recipient@example.com <<'HERE'
Subject: Test

Date: 20131004
HERE
```